# How to use custom sbt version in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have a scala sbt project. When I open a terminal in intellij and do sbt sbtVersion, I see 0.13.8. I want to use my own local install that is 0.13.5. When I open up a new command prompt, I see that the sbt version is 0.13.5, but in the IntelliJ terminal, it keeps saying 0.13.8 even though I configured my "Settings->SBT" to point to a custom "sbt-launch.jar" instead of bundled. How to I get IntelliJ to use my "older version" of SBT?

My main problem I am getting is this:

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I heard that SBT 0.13.5 is the version to use, but I am having trouble telling IntelliJ to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As shown in the screenshot it is under

> Preferences | Build,Execution,Deployment | Build Tools | SBT .

In that dialog it is the last option under

> Launcher (sbt-launch.jar)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. in ubuntu, with sbt installed from https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian the path is /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar

Comment: ```sudo find / -name sbt-launch.jar``` gives me ```/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar```, too

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody still needs it: `sbt-launcher.jar` location on MacOS: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sbt/1.9.0/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar`