# Locally Installed SBT , SCALA ,Intellij. Want to use locally installed sbt,scala in project

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I am new to Intellij IDE.

I have created a SBT project on Intellij(2016.1.3). whenever i finish project create wizard, its started downloading sbt, scala versions through internet.But
I want to use locally installed sbt,scala versions. I have read below thread; My SBT don't have 'sbt-launch.jar'

[How to use custom sbt version in intellij idea 14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253127/how-to-use-custom-sbt-version-in-intellij-idea-14)

locally installed SBT version :0.13.11 ( in Ubuntu file system, it is with " .sbt   " name, as hidden folder) & Scala Version  :2.10.5 (java 1.8)

Kindly, plzz tell me how to use locally installed versions in SBT project.

Thanks in advance,
Raghav

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-sbt.html

Comment: @MikeCheel : I have read that . In 4th point screenshot, there is "download : source , Source for SBT and plugins" check box. it causing  download scala SBT through internet. Thanks alot for response.

Comment: Your best bet would be to put in a ticket with jet brains for this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us You can click submit a request in the upper right of the page. They usually get back to you within 8 hours although my experience has been it is normally even faster than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My SBT don't have 'sbt-launch.jar'.

If SBT is properly installed, then there *is* a `sbt-launch.jar` somwhere. Assuming you installed SBT [with the DEB package](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html), you should be able to list installed files with the command `dpkg -L sbt`.

> locally installed SBT version :0.13.11 ( in Ubuntu file system, it is with " .sbt " name, as hidden folder)

Sounds like you are talking about the `~/.sbt` folder? This is SBT's default location for storing user data (user-specific configuration, but also some cached downloads), not the installation folder.

> But I want to use locally installed sbt,scala versions.

There are actually three elements to consider:

- The SBT laucher (`sbt-launch.jar`)
- SBT itself
- Scala (compiler & standard library)

For the SBT launcher, you can use your own install or let Intellij download its own copy.

For SBT, realistically, I think it *will* have to be downloaded by the SBT launcher. The version of SBT to use is specified in `<my project>/project/build.properties`.

For Scala, you can let SBT download it (usually recommended; configure the version to use in your `build.sbt`) or use a local version.

If you really want to use a local Scala version, this is [explained in the SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Configuring-Scala.html#Switching+to+a+local+Scala+version): you should just need to configure `scalaHome` in you `build.sbt`:

```
scalaHome := Some(file("/home/user/scala-2.10/"))
```

But keep in mind that this will make you build less repeatable, both on other computers or on the same computer after a few months have passed... And managing several projects which may require different versions of Scala will also be more difficult.